# WildFly returns "Not found"

Tags: windows, jakarta-ee, wildfly

**Context:**
I've developed a web-app on Linux Mint using JavaEE 7 on WildFly. My customer has Windows XP and I need to deploy on it. The app is done and I am trying to deploy it (for testing) on my VM on XP. The admin-console works fine. There are also no errors when deploying the app. WildFly registers the app to /app.

**Problem:** When I try to access the app on `http://localhost:8080/app` WildFly returns `Forbidden` if I try to access `http://localhost:8080/app/hello.xhtml` it returns just "Not found" (No 404).

**Note:** This is my first web-app and I have no idea where to troubleshoot since there are no errors in the log. Any help is much appreciated.

- Java EE7
- WildFly 9.0.1 Final
- Windows XP SP3

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
<context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.enableMissingResourceLibraryDetection</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>BootsFaces_USETHEME</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
    <param-value>afternoon</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
    <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DATETIMECONVERTER_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE_IS_SYSTEM_TIMEZONE</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<error-page>
    <exception-    type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
    <location>/desktop.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

jboss-web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web xmlns="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee">
    <context-root>/app</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

Comment: did you ever find the solution to this? I have the same problem :(

Comment: As far as I remember it was a problem with the context-path. I think I've declared them in an inconsistent manner.